# MDBootstrap: Clear table editor so that the content can be re-inserted

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mdbootstrap

**Expected behavior:** I have a table where some of the data is already in there but maybe also an empty table. The user should enter the data there and later save it to the database using Buttun. This also works, but I want to empty the table if successful so that the user can create a new entry directly.

**Actual behavior:** The data is deleted with the help of JavaScript. But if I click on the + then the deleted data is included. So you have to remove it manually. It looks like the data is not stored separately somewhere and I wonder how I can delete it permanently?

**Here is a snippet:** https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/extox/5962683